# How to keep data between intervals with Workmanager/PeriodicWorkRequest

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I need a variable in the IntervalWork class keeping it's data throughout the different calls or intervals. Making the variable static or global within the class doesn't work. How to?

IntervalWork('keep' always loses it's value):

```
  public class IntervalWork{
    static int keep;
    public result doWork(){
       keep++;
     }
  }
```

MainActivity:

```
        Constraints IntervalWorkerCS = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            .build();
    //W/WM-WorkSpec: Interval duration lesser than minimum allowed value; Changed to 900000(15 minutes)
    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(IntervalWork.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .setConstraints(IntervalWorkerCS)
            .setInitialDelay(delay,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag("MyID")
            .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).cancelAllWork();
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("MyID", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWork);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your process may be terminated in between work items. So, if you have data that you wish to hold onto, save it in a file (database, `SharedPreferences`, etc.) or on a server.